# Apache2 Suddenly the website doesn´t show and load index.php

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache2

I'm currently learning to work with **php** and **Javascript** with **apache2**.
Everything were fine, but after I added xhr.onreadystatechange and the function related with it nothing loaded. When I wanted to see the file from the Browser there were nothing, but it was only with index.php like that. Also after I rebooted and restated.
But when I make a index.html file everything load fine.
I have also PHP enabled.

Here is the **index.php** file, that doesn´t load:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"):
        echo $POST[];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="de">
        <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>Steuerung</title>

<script>
  // Das XMLHttpRequest-Objekt setzen
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var keyCode = 0;

  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
   document.onkeydown = function(event) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("var")[1].innerHTML = event.keyCode;
        //keyCode = event.KeyCode;
        //ausführen();
   }
  });

  function ausführen() {
        document.getElementsByTagName("var")[0].innerHTML = "ne";
        xhr.open("POST", document.URL, true);
        xhr.send(keyCode);

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 &&
                xhr.status == 200) {
                        if (xhr.responseText == "OK") {
                                document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].innerHTML = 'Die Daten wurden gesendet.';
                        }
                        else {
                                document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].innerHTML = 'No';
                        }
                }
        }
  }

  </script>

 </head>
<body>

<form>

 <p>
  <label>Name: <var>*</var><br>
  <input type="text" name="name"></label>
 </p>

 <p>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="agb"> AGB gelesen</label>
  <var>*</var>
 </p>

 <p>
  <label>Text: <var>*</var><br>
  <textarea name="txt" rows="4" cols="25"></textarea></label>
 </p>

 <p>
  <input type="button" name="send" value="Absenden">
 </p>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This: "_but after a change suddenly nothing loaded_" - So then, what changed? Don't you think that is important to the question? And please don't suggest that you don't know. It could anything you've done recently the caused this. Think back and tell us everything you've changed recently.

Comment: `echo $POST[];` should probably be `echo $_POST[];`. The first is a regular variable and would not exist, the second is a server variable. You're probably getting a white screen/error 500 because of it

Comment: No, I changed $POST[] to $_POST[] but I still get a white screen. But if I comment out the two php line(if... and echo...) I doesnt get a white screen

Comment: try with 
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
print_r($_POST)
?>

Comment: Thank you. I now get an output. On top of the website there is a added Array(). But its not quite what I want. The echo $_POST[]; was just there to test if I get something back and can get it displayed. I wanna use the $_POST[] variable if I get and request and depending on it value(a keyCode) I want to execute other files and then echo OK or something else

Comment: After some trial and error I finally got it working. I forgot a `endif;` after the if statement